# openstack swift: The server has waited too long for the request to be sent by the client

Tags: openstack, rackspace-cloud, openstack-swift, cloudfiles, jclouds

we get few of these now and then:

```
Caused by: javax.ejb.EJBException: org.jclouds.http.HttpResponseException: 
command: PUT {{PUT_URL}} 
HTTP/1.1 failed with response: HTTP/1.1 408 Request Timeout; 
content: [<html><h1>Request Timeout</h1><p>The server has waited too long for the request to be sent by the client.</p></html>]
```

retrying later usually works. what causes this exception? is there a way to increase the timeout on swift?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jclouds 1.7.2 includes a fix for this issue:

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/JCLOUDS-342

Answer (score 1):

Your question does not have the proper info in detail.

if you are a developer you can use something like:

```
import static org.jclouds.Constants.*;


  Properties overrides = new Properties();
  overrides.setProperty(PROPERTY_MAX_CONNECTIONS_PER_CONTEXT, 20 + "");
  overrides.setProperty(PROPERTY_MAX_CONNECTIONS_PER_HOST, 0 + "");
  overrides.setProperty(PROPERTY_CONNECTION_TIMEOUT, 5000 + "");
  overrides.setProperty(PROPERTY_SO_TIMEOUT, 5000 + "");
  overrides.setProperty(PROPERTY_IO_WORKER_THREADS, 20 + "");
  // unlimited user threads
  overrides.setProperty(PROPERTY_USER_THREADS, 0 + "");


  Set<Module> wiring =  ImmutableSet.of(new EnterpriseConfigurationModule(), new Log4JLoggingModule());

  // same properties and wiring can be used for many services, although the limits are per context
  blobStoreContext = ContextBuilder.newBuilder("s3")
                      .credentials(account, key)
                      .modules(wiring)
                      .overrides(overrides)
                      .buildView(BlobStoreContext.class);
  computeContext = ContextBuilder.newBuilder("ec2")
                      .credentials(account, key)
                      .modules(wiring)
                      .overrides(overrides)
                      .buildView(ComputeServiceContext.class);
```

Following is the quote from [JClouds Configuration docs](https://jclouds.apache.org/reference/configuration/):

**Timeout**:
    Aggregate commands will take as long as necessary to complete, as controlled by FutureIterables.awaitCompletion.
    If you need to increase or decrease this, you will need to adjust the property jclouds.request-timeout or Constants.PROPERTY_REQUEST_TIMEOUT.
    This is described in the Advanced Configuration section.

If you are dealing with your own cluster then you can go with some possible configuration options present in swift [proxy-server-configuration](http://docs.openstack.org/developer/swift/deployment_guide.html?highlight=proxy%20server#proxy-server-configuration).